# RealTime graph using wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

How can I make a real time graph using wxWidgets in Windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try some of the wxWidget specific controls linked to below. I have only ever worked with wxMathPlot which fitted my needs but is not necessarily fast - it depends on your time requirements for real time and amount of data you are trying to plot.

[wxMathPlot](http://wxmathplot.sourceforge.net)

[wxPlot & plplot](http://personales.unican.es/carreracg/web/wxplot.html)

[wxChart](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/components/wxchart/)

[wxFreeChart](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/components/freechart/)

[gpPanel - seems to have forked from wxMathPlot](http://code.google.com/p/gppanel/)

There are probably others too, and you could even write your own using any number of the 2D drawing controls that are available, or write your own custom control.

Comment: I use wxMathPlot and find it plenty fast - a scrolling oscilloscope style plot with thousands of points and tens of new points per second.

Comment: thanks alot ... I'll have a look at all of these and will come back to u if i have any more questions ...