# How Can use the Wxwidgets for plotting?

Tags: plot, makefile, wxwidgets, using

I am working as researcher at University of Genoa in Italy. I am using the C++ during my work at this Univeristy (I am new in using Visual C++). I would like to know "How can use Wxwidgets library to plot two columns from Matrix that includes on 4 columns?"

From another side, If there in any documentions that relate with Wxwidgets library that should help me to understand "How can I make plotting??", please send me the links for these documentions....

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for plotting in wxWidgets.
There is however number of libraries you can use located [here](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/complist.php).
One of them is [wxFreeChart](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxcode/files/Components/wxFreeChart/) last updated 2010 (and so no problem with wx 2.8). [SVN Version](http://sourceforge.net/p/wxcode/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/wxCode/components/freechart/) seem to show some life so its your best bet!

Comment: Dear sir, Thank you very much on your interesting... I would like to know "Can I use this library if I used Visual C ++ (2012)??" Can you please support me with some links (include some examples) to know "How can I use "wxFreeChart" in plotting??"

Comment: check samples that come with downloads. note that am not author. he can be found on wxwidgets forum

Answer (score 0):

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898205/realtime-graph-using-wxwidgets). [wxFreeChar](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/components/freechart/) is probably the most promising of the libraries mentioned there and should allow you to plot just about anything (I'm really not sure about what do you mean by plotting matrix columns...).

Comment: Dear Sir, Thank you very much on your interesting.... If I have matrix two columns and I want to ploting (X,Y) where X indicates to first column and Y indicates to the second column... My supervisor wants me to do that by using the Wxplot but the problem is that I didn't find any example on the Internet till now learn me "How can I do that by using the Wxplot??"